# how to obtain a type-safe enum value from a string?

Tags: typescript

I have defined a string-based enum. What is the idiomatic way to obtain type safe enum objects out of untyped strings?

E.g. what should I do in the following:

```
enum Car {
    BMW = 'bmw',
    AUDI = 'audi'
}

const car = 'bmw';
const typedCar: Car = // ??
```

The suggested way of doing a:

```
const typedCar: Car = Car[car];
```

(as suggested e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17381004/274677)) does not work for String Enums AFAICT.

Comment: You can use `as` keyword to tell TS `car` type `const typedCar = car as Car;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the enum key with the value string (reverse mapping) in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297376/getting-the-enum-key-with-the-value-string-reverse-mapping-in-typescript)

Comment: @ritaj The presently accepted answer to that question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54297863/274677) does not type check and if one edits it to type check assertions are still needed so it is not clear to me why it is superior to the much simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63671601/274677

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assert that it is a `car` by using the `as` keyword.

The code would be `const typedCar = car as Car;`