# Key to enum mapping

Tags: typescript, enums, obsidian

I'm working on an Obsidian plugin where I have created an `enum` to represent the setting for the background pattern.

In the settings menu of the plugin, I'm showing a drop down menu, and added all the `enum` values to it.

When the user changes the state of the drop down menu, I want to set the value they select in my `settings` object, but I can't get an `enum` value from the key or value of the `enum`.

This is my code for creating the setting in Obsidian:

```js
new Setting(backgroundContainer)
            .setName('Pattern')
            .setDesc('Choose a pattern to use for the background.')
            .addDropdown(dropdown => {

                for(const key in BackgroundPattern) {
    
                    if (Number(key) >= 0) {
    
                        dropdown.addOption(key, BackgroundPattern[key]);
                    }
                }
                dropdown.onChange(async (value) =>{
                    const key = Number(value)
                    let pattern = BackgroundPattern[value as keyof typeof BackgroundPattern];
                    this.plugin.settings.background.pattern = pattern;
                })
            })
```

I am using the setting when drawing the background:

```js
round(): void {
    const stageWidth = this.stage.width();
    const stageHeight = this.stage.height();

    this.backgroundLayer.destroyChildren();

    console.log(this.settings.background.pattern)
    console.log(typeof this.settings.background.pattern)

    switch (this.settings.background.pattern) {
        case BackgroundPattern.grid:
            //draw vertical lines
            for (let x = 0; x < stageWidth; x += this.settings.background.size) {
                this.backgroundLayer.add(new Line({
                    stroke: this.settings.background.color,
                    points: [x, 0, x, stageHeight],
                    name: 'vertical'
                }))
            }
        //no break to run next case and draw lines of grid
        case BackgroundPattern.line:
            //draw horizontal lines
            for (let y = 0; y < stageHeight; y += this.settings.background.size) {
                this.backgroundLayer.add(new Line({
                    stroke: this.settings.background.color,
                    points: [0, y, stageWidth, y],
                    name: 'horizontal'
                }))
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

When the `drawBackground` method is called, I get `grid` and `string` in the console, but no background is drawn, so the switch case statement fails when comparing the `setting` to `BackgroundPattern`.

To better understand this behavior, I created this snippet to isolate the conversion:

```js
enum BackgroundPattern {
    blank,
    line,
    grid
}

for (const key in BackgroundPattern) {
    if (Number(key) >= 0) {
        console.log(key, BackgroundPattern[key])
    }
}

const key = String(0) //or 1 or 2

//first try
let reversed = BackgroundPattern[key as keyof typeof BackgroundPattern];
console.log(reversed)
console.log(typeof reversed)

//second try
//taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54297863/11908728
let reversed2 = Object.values(BackgroundPattern).find((val) => {
    return val === BackgroundPattern[Number(key)]
});
console.log(reversed2)
console.log(typeof reversed2)

console.log('check comparison:')
if(reversed2 == BackgroundPattern.blank) {
    console.log('blank')
}
if(reversed2 == BackgroundPattern.grid) {
    console.log('grid')
}
if(reversed2 == BackgroundPattern.line) {
    console.log('line')
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAQghgYwNYHMBOB7MIAmAFOAF0ODRCgG8AoKWqAIwBs4QkAaGuxgSxGA7pR03HFQC+VKgDMMaKAAoEGEAGdCUJMACeUXrESpM2fERJkAlJU61uUhQDlI9UvM1bLAPgC8UAAyXqQUElVQxGYAA6RgwUV202fWR0LFwCYlIQAG03AF1zaygJCSoQtQ1tKB8AZUI0Xlj-KAB6JtkoAEYoNoAmSRapbjQy2q0qcPU0YAA3UhVgHErEwxSTdLJsirgVcq0MO0ItAAdgPaXk4zSzEByAbhLlFTDI6NjJmaH5-NKnqJj5A+Opzes0+fSacxCCxGVBahDgmnIUkw0AAFsRDioAFwtNQGDDvKTRADuESUECacCaAFYACzdACcAHYABwANgAzE12u16b5mYzusyxsAJtMQThuosAPL0ABWwAQhAiUzgjDAwBU8ngSSMqVMGXMEQGuHk8hVjEsXg8VkEk0IYDIUHNlS8Pm1ywu+vWjggzjQcXcOXE5ju33Cv1eYo+Eq+Dx+L3+RxOdmB0e6+SAA)
Independent of what I'm setting `key` to, none of the three comparison at the end work.

What should I do, to get a value for my setting, that I can later compare it to with the `BackgroundPattern` enum to decide which background to draw?

Comment: Sorry, what is "the enum itself"? What exact thing do you expect to see in your output or the typing? If your question truly depends on "obsidian" then I don't know what to say, but if the code at the bottom is supposed to be a [mre] without it, then please consider [edit]ing so that the problem jumps out at us when we look at it, either with an error somewhere it shouldn't be, or a clear disagreement between some actual behavior and expected behavior, preferably as evidenced by something being false when it should be true or vice versa.

Comment: `reversed instanceof BackgroundPattern` is impossible. `enum` values aren't class instances, they're just plain numbers or strings. Please clarify what you mean by "`typeof reversed` is `BackgroundPattern`". There's a runtime `typeof` operator in JS and a compile type `typeof` operator in TS and they do very different things. Where, specifically, do you expect to see `typeof reversed` to be `BackgroundPattern`? Again, it's always helpful if you show this stuff in the code itself, instead of describing it in a mixture of code and words. If the snippet is a [mre] the issue should jump out at us.

Comment: I don't understand why you're not just turning `"0"` into `0` yourself; it's just `Number()`, right? Why are you bothering to "look it up" and turn it into the same thing? If you want to do that [you can do so as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/mAa3km) but I really don't get it. It's baffling to me. Was this what you wanted or is/was it something else?

Comment: @jcalz maybe I just don't get how enums work in typescript and expect them to work differently then they are implemented

Comment: Other than linking to [the documentation for enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html), what could we do to help? Are you trying to turn `"0"` into `0` or are you trying to do something else? Could you [edit] the question to give a clear objective so that we know what a correct answer might look like? Maybe you want to rephrase to just describe the underlying use case? Is it "how do I iterate over the values of a numeric enum?" If so then I'd suggest [something like this instead](https://tsplay.dev/NBdZzW). Does that fully address the question?